# Docker can not up Nginx and Nginx htpasswd never detecting

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, devops, elastic-stack

Hi I am trying to establish ELK stack + Nginx(for load balancing and basic Auth) by using Docker. My question is : I couldn't use Nginx as loadbalancer and when I try to visit kibana web ui, Never asking to me any password. How can I rearrange my docker compose for security and load balancing? Iam using windows 10.

My file structure is below:

[image: file structure]

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
 services:
 elasticsearch:
container_name: esc
image: esi:1.0.0
build: ./es
volumes:
  - ./data/es:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
ports:
    - 9200:9200
expose:
    - 9300
kibana:
container_name: kibanac
image: kibanai:1.0.0
build: ./kibana
links:
  - elasticsearch
ports:
  - 5601:5601
nginx:
image: nginx:latest
restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  - ./nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro,Z
  - ./nginx/htpasswd.users:/etc/nginx/htpasswd.users:ro,Z
ports:
  - "8890:8890"
depends_on:
  - elasticsearch
  - kibana
```

Docker deamons:

[image]

Nginx.conf:

```
  upstream elasticsearch {
 server localhost:9200;
    keepalive 15;
 }

 upstream kibana {
server localhost:5601;
keepalive 15;
 }

server {
listen 8888;

location / {
  auth_basic           "Protected Elasticsearch";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

  proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_buffering off;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
  proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
  }

}

 server {
 listen 8889;

 location / {
  auth_basic           "Protected Kibana";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

  proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_buffering off;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
  proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
}

}

Kibana.yml:  ( calling for kibana ui-> localhost:5601)

 server.name: kibana
 server.host: "0"
 elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200
 elasticsearch.username: elastic
 elasticsearch.password: changeme
 xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true

Elasticsearch.yml:  ( calling for elasticsearch-> localhost:9200)

 http.host: 0.0.0.0

 ### x-pack functions
 xpack.security.enabled: false

 xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
 xpack.graph.enabled: false
 xpack.watcher.enabled: false

Dockerfile for Kibana:
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.2

COPY ./config/kibana.yml /opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml

Dockerfile for Elasticsearch: 
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.2

COPY ./config/elasticsearch.yml 
/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

Comment: what's URL for your access to kibana ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan; I updated above code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add ip address or domain name in nginx configuration which you are accessing Kibana web UI.

```
listen ip_address_or_domain_name:8889;
```

and:

```
proxy_pass http://kibana;
```

In docker-compose.yml file:

```
ports:
  - "8890:8889"
```

Please note, its port 8889.

Access : http://ip_address_or_domain_name:8890